# Getting critical points of diff eq system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have to calculate the critical points of the following system.
$$x'=cx+10x^2$$
$$y'=x-2y$$
So I solve the system 
$$cx+10x^2=0$$
$$x-2y=0$$
So if $x=2y$ I have $2yc+10*4y^2=2yc+40y^2=y(2c+40y)=0$ and I get $y=0$ and $y=-\frac{c}{20}$ f I substitute in $x=2y$ I get $x=0$ and $x=-\frac{c}{10}$
Then we have that the critical points are $(0,0)$ and $(-\frac{c}{10},-\frac{c}{20})$
Is this correct? I don't know if the procedure to get the critical points is like this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, indeed you have to solve the system

$$\begin{cases} cx + 10x^2 = 0 \\ x-2y = 0 \end{cases}$$

since a critical point $\mathbf{x_0}$ is a point such that $\mathbf{f'(x_0) = 0}$ (bold is used to denote vector notation since we have a 2-D system).

Your final calculations are correct as well. It would be useful to give a "name" to each critical point, such that it can be easily used during rest calculations etc.

For stability, consider the Jacobian matrix of your system :

$$J(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} c+20x & 0 \\ 1 & -2\end{bmatrix}$$

Substitute now each of the critical points at a time and proceed with finding the corresponding eigenvalues to determine the kind of stability.

Comment: Thank you for solving my doubts. They also ask me to determine what kind of point is each one acording to their eigenvalues for different values of c. I thought about solving the problem in general using the jacobian and determining the eigenvalues $\lambda=-2$ $\lambda=c+20x$and then for each critical point give to c a positive, a negative and a 0 value. Would be this the best effcient way?

Comment: You mean, the stability of each critical point ?

Comment: yes, stability and type of point (saddle, etc..) sorry i was editing the text

Comment: @Physpilot I updated my answer accordingly. If an answer, in general, is helpful, you may use the vote buttons and the one that answers your question the best, you may accept that one by clicking on the tick marker.

Comment: Yes, but which values should I give to c? c=0 for sure but maybe also a positive and a negative one? Yes, thank you! but I can not give up votes because I dont have reputation points

Comment: @Physpilot Carry out the calculations first and then see.

Comment: Ok thank you, I just discovered that I can tick your answer

Comment: The problem is that when c=0 I obtain a null eigenvalue and I can't relate this to any type of critical point

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your answer is correct.

The critical points are where the derivatives are zero and you  have found $(0,0)$ and $(\frac {-c}{10},\frac {-c}{20})$ which make both derivatives zero.